# Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host thrown in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-javascript-sdk

Yesterday was fine, but today, suddenly, my web app report an error while accessing Facebook PHP API. 
At first, the error was connection time out. So, I added the time in base_facebook.php, changed the variable 
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10 into 
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60

Now, my web app reports another error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host thrown in xxx\src\base_facebook.php on line 972

Ah, I run my app on localhost in Windows (XAMPP 1.7.7).
For testing it, I also run the example codes from the newest facebook API in github. 
I also have restarted my Apache server, and It still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a server configuration problem on your side.

Check whether the host has blocked the ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Thank you @sahil, how to check if the port has blocked? I Checked using netstat -a -n, both port are listening.